# the asset assets/appimage/test.png does not exist warning in pubspec.yaml

Tags: image, exception, flutter, dart

Please find the below code
**main.dart:**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key); 
   final String title; 

   @override 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold( 
         appBar: AppBar( title: Text(this.title), ), 
         body: Center( child: Image.asset("assets/smiley.png")),
      ); 
   }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: product_app
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/appimages/floppy.png
    - assets/appimages/iphone.png
    - assets/appimages/laptop.png
    - assets/appimages/pendrive.png
    - assets/appimages/pixel.png
    - assets/appimages/tablet.png
```

Before execution; the asset assets/appimage/test.png does not exist warning in pubspec.yaml
After executing the code below exception is coming

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞══
I/flutter ( 8653): The following assertion was thrown while resolving an image:
    I/flutter ( 8653): Unable to load asset: AssetManifest.json
    I/flutter ( 8653): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    I/flutter ( 8653): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
    I/flutter ( 8653): <asynchronous suspension>
    I/flutter ( 8653): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:67:33)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:163:18)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #3      CachingAssetBundle.loadStructuredData (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:184:5)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #4      AssetImage.obtainKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:174:18)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:318:15)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #9      ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:315:16)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #10     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1010:20)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #11     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:967:5)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #12     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4376:12)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
    I/flutter ( 8653): #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
```

Comment: perform flutter clean command from terminal and "smiley.png" does not exists in pubspec please add image in assert/appimages folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**And You can simply define in your `pubspec.yaml` file like below Not need to define all images in your `.yaml file`**

```
assets:
- assets/appimages/    (it will include all images in your appimages folder)
```

**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key); 
   final String title; 

   @override 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold( 
         appBar: AppBar( title: Text(this.title), ), 
         body: Center( child: Image.asset("assets/appimages/iphone.png")),
      ); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I did put the same but it's still message doesn't exist

Answer (score 16):

My friend .. move your assets folder out of the lib folder -> it is a project-based folder .. after that, your code will work fine.
Also, in the `pubspec.yaml` make it `assets/appimages/`  as `Aamil Silawat` said.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
- lib/assets/images/
```

main.dart

```
Image.asset(
    'lib/assets/images/gato.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover
  ),
```

Comment: The assets folder should be moved out of the lib folder, it is a project-based folder.

Answer (score 1):

See Sometimes it shows that the **{your image folder}** is outside your lib folder **(I mean it is not in any in any folder)** in the file explorer but if you look carefully **(in the editor explorer)** the folder resides in lib or any other folder it id not free **((in my case this happened))**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just save directly in lib. and write "lib/imagename".extension Worked for me.

And if this don't work then change your channel to beta. and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).